# Integration Grizzly2.2.X with Jersey and Spring

Tags: java, spring, web, jersey, grizzly

I have successfully integrated `Grizzly v2.1.9` with `Jersey` and `Spring`. But could not make it work when trying to migrate `Grizzly` to version `2.2.19`.

The original code with `Grizzly v2.1.9` is as below.

```
HttpServer server = new HttpServer();
NetworkListener listener = new NetworkListener("grizzly2", "localhost", 3388);
server.addListener(listener);

ServletHandler sa = new ServletHandler();       
sa.setContextPath("/");     
sa.setServletInstance(new SpringServlet());
sa.addContextParameter("contextConfigLocation", "classpath:spring-context.xml");                
sa.addServletListener("org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener");
sa.addServletListener("org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener");                

ServerConfiguration config = server.getServerConfiguration();
config.addHttpHandler(sa, new String[] {"/"});
server.start();
```

And the new code with `Grizzly v2.2.19` is as below

```
HttpServer server = new HttpServer();
NetworkListener listener = new NetworkListener("grizzly2", "localhost", 3388);
WebappContext ctx = new WebappContext("ctx","/");       
final ServletRegistration reg = ctx.addServlet("spring", new SpringServlet());
reg.addMapping("/*");
ctx.addContextInitParameter("contextConfigLocation", "classpath:spring-context.xml");
ctx.addListener("org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener");         
ctx.addListener("org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener");
ctx.deploy(server);
server.start();
```

The new code could be compiled and executed with no exception. However all urls which should be forwarded to different methods by `Jersey` are  now all forwarded to the default page "/".

**UPDATE**

For someone who meets the same problem.

It is fixed after Grizzly2.2.20

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I get a workaround after sending an email to java.net.

Change

```
WebappContext ctx = new WebappContext("ctx","/");
```

to

```
WebappContext ctx = new WebappContext("ctx","");
```

Can follow this [link](http://grizzly.1045725.n5.nabble.com/Integration-Grizzly2-2-X-with-Jersey-and-Spring-td5710024.html) for more detail.